# Angular 8 cant get data from API always return 404

Tags: api, angular8

1. I'm using API from twitch.
2. I have checked API on postman its work correctly

   - twitch API => https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/follows?to_id=TWITCH_ID_IS_HERE&first=100
   - Header => Client-ID: CLIENT-ID-IS-HERE
3. I am tested another API on my angular 8 projects still works correctly.

   Example

   {  _total: 35, videos: Array(10)  }

   ```
      zone.js:3372 XHR finished loading: GET"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/TWITCH_ID_IS_HERE/videos".
   ```

   [exam post data from api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKRWP.png)

4.this is dataset return from broken Service API

- twitch API => https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/follows?to_id=TWITCH_ID_IS_HERE&first=100
- Header => Client-ID: CLIENT-ID-IS-HERE

```
      body: {
          error: "'users' with id='follows' not found"
      }, 
      url: "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/follows?
       to_id=TWITCH_ID_IS_HERE&first=100", 
      headers: HttpHeaders, 
      status: 404, 
      statusText: "Not Found"
    }
```

5.service function

```
  async getUserFollows(twitchId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/follows', {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Client-ID': this.clientId
            }), params: new HttpParams()
                .set('to_id', twitchId)
                .set('first', '100')
            }).subscribe(
                (res: any) => {
                    resolve(res);
                }, err => {
                    reject(err);
                }
            );
        }
    );
  }
```

What should I do? What am I missing?

Comment: What do you have in your "Network" tab in the browser, does the request look good to you?

Comment: am not found any requested "api.twitch.tv/helix/users/follows" in-network tab anymore the last request is another function on Article 3.

Comment: I request 3 service 
1.channel desc
2.stream 
3.follower
I found only 1, 2 but not found 3 on network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `async` keyword, because you are already using a Promise.

The request never gets fired because you are returning a Promise of Promise (and since nobody listens on the outer Promise, it never gets fired).

You would have caught this error if you had typed the return type of the function - a good practice you could consider.

By the way, you code would be cleaner using

```
this.http.get<...>(...)
         .pipe(..., catchError(...))
         .toPromise();
```